# After migration from MVC3 to MVC4 I got an error my Theme view page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I migrated my ASP.NET MVC3 solution to MVC4. Everything goes well until I 'injected' the Theme part. I checked old (MVC3) / new (MVC4) versions of my solution and everything seems ok but I got the error below:

[image]

[image]

Here is an extract of the Web.Config file for the "Default" Theme:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="MyBlog.Core.ApplicationViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="MyBlog" />
        <add namespace="MyBlog.Models" />
        <add namespace="MyBlog.Resources" />
        <add namespace="MyBlog.Helpers"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
  ....
```

**As you can see, the pageBaseType is "MyBlog.Core.ApplicationViewPage"**

Here is the ApplicationViewPage class:

```
public abstract class ApplicationViewPage<TModel> : WebViewPage<TModel>
{
    public SiteConfiguration SiteConfiguration { get; private set; }

    public override void InitHelpers()
    {
        SiteConfiguration = SiteManager.CurrentConfiguration;
        base.InitHelpers();
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure this is a stupid problem but I'm not able to fint it !

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `1 to the pageBaseType attribute value

```
<pages pageBaseType="MyBlog.Core.ApplicationViewPage`1">
```